# How to align upload and input field in the same line?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I am trying to align upload button and a text field which displays the file name in the same line with some gap in between. It's not coming in the same line at all.

This is the code I have written:

```
<div>

  <Form.Item name='fileupload' getValueFromEvent={e => handleChange(e)} value='file'>
    <Upload maxCount={1} showUploadList={false} beforeUpload={() => false}>
      <Button type='primary' className='upload-button'> Upload </Button>
    </Upload>
  </Form.Item>

  <div style={{float:"right"}}>
    <input className='file-name' style={{height: "40px", width: "400px"}} value={filename}></input>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my css file

```
.upload-button {
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  flex: none;
}
.file-name {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I used antd Space to align it but when I used that getValueFromEvent function never gets called. Form item needs to have only upload button for that function to be called. So, when I do that, the buttons are coming in different lines. What do I add to my code to put them in the same line?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of how this renders in plain HTML elements once run the browser? Looking for the DOM element involved. Such as what do <Form.Item> and <Upload> components render as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few modifications you need to make to bring the upload button and the input on the same like,

Create a parent div as wrapper to the upload button and input box and give [**display as flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for the parent wrapper,

```
   <div className="input-wrapper">
      <Form.Item
        name="fileupload"
        getValueFromEvent={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        value="file"
      >
        <Upload maxCount={1} showUploadList={false} beforeUpload={() => false}>
          <Button type="primary" className="upload-button">
            {" "}
            Upload{" "}
          </Button>
        </Upload>
      </Form.Item>

      <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
        <input
          className="file-name"
          value={filename}
          style={{ height: "40px", width: "400px" }}
        ></input>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And then make few changes of css like moving `gap: 8px` to the `input-wrapper` div and can remove `align-items: center` and `flex: none` from the `.upload-button` and css looks like,

```
.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
}
.upload-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
.file-name {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit Ant design file upload (forked)]

*Also as a note please consider having styles in the css file alone instead of making it inline.*

Comment: @Renee, Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox on the container element to wrap them like below

```
<div style={{display: "flex", gap: "6px" }}>

  <Form.Item name='fileupload' getValueFromEvent={e => handleChange(e)} value='file'>
    <Upload maxCount={1} showUploadList={false} beforeUpload={() => false}>
      <Button type='primary' className='upload-button'> Upload </Button>
    </Upload>
  </Form.Item>

  <div>
    <input className='file-name' style={{height: "40px", width: "400px"}} value={filename}></input>
  </div>

</div>
```

You also can use a class name to have cleaner styles

```
<div className="flexbox">
...
</div>
```

```
.flexbox {
   display: flex; /* Flexbox display */
   gap: 6px; /* Create a gap between elements */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not tried flex for the parent class. It's working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You can add another div to the form.item like this

```
<div class="flex_container">
   <div>
     <Form.Item name='fileupload' getValueFromEvent={e => handleChange(e)} 
     value='file'>
     <Upload maxCount={1} showUploadList={false} beforeUpload={() => false}>
     <Button type='primary' className='upload-button'> Upload </Button>
     </Upload>
     </Form.Item>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input className='file-name' style={{height: "40px", width: "400px"}} 
 value={filename}></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your css file

```
.flex_container {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   justify-content:right; //or whatever you wish
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was able to resolve the issue.